# VK (vkontakte) API Error: Access denied when trying to post to the wall

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, vk

I got the token by authorizing the user with this URL:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const VK_CLIENT_ID = '1231231';

const photos = 4;
const wall = 8192;
const offline = 65536;
const scope = offline + wall + photos;

const URL = `https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=${VK_CLIENT_ID}&display=popup&redirect_uri=http://example.com/auth/vk&scope=${scope}&response_type=token&v=5.78`;

const accessToken = '...';
const ownerID = '212121212';

fetch(
  `https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?v=5.78&message=test_api&owner_id=${ownerID}&access_token=${accessToken}`
)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(body => console.log(body));
```

Error:

```
{
  error: {
    error_code: 15,
    error_msg: "Access denied: no access to call this method",
    request_params: [
      { key: "oauth", value: "1" },
      { key: "method", value: "wall.post" },
      { key: "v", value: "5.78" },
      { key: "message", value: "test_api" },
      { key: "owner_id", value: "184591202" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason. It's not possible to use this API method. You need a Standalone VK Application (for desktop or mobile apps) and then the User needs to approve posting to the wall.

See this [VK API, access denied for post on wall of a community, fail WALL Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41494966/728287)